# Extrapolation of CRISPR

Tags: quantum-algorithms, quantum-biology

Can quantum computing do a simple simulated extrapolation of **CRISPR** (clustered regularly interspaced short palindromic repeats) projects using a limited number of variables? I mean something like finding short clusters of palindrome repeats in a genome sequence, where the binding can take place.

<sup>**Note:** I am not qualified in the CRISPR area, and this is a question a client has asked. I would love any input and even questions to feedback for extra information.</sup>